# Encrypt entire disk

Tags: encryption

I have multiple OS on my machine (debian, ubuntu and windows) I already have ubuntu and windows disks encrypted separately.

I'm thinking about backing up all my data and reinstalling everything this week end, I want to know if there's a way to encrypt my entire disk instead of encrypting each OS.

I don't know how to do a hardware-based full disk encryption (from the wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption) this may be the solution to my answer), I know the risks of doing such operation I just don't have enough information to start with. How to know if my HDD supports it ?

It would be very helpful to have any documentation about this process.

---

Edit :

My HDD is not compatible with hardware-based full disk encryption. I've found this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14227/multi-boot-with-full-hard-drive-encryption-and-pre-boot-authentication but not sure if it's still relevant. Could it be the answer to my issue ?

Comment: Windows and Linux, while both supporting full-disk encryption, do so in separate and incompatible ways, and (that I'm aware) there's no cross-compatibility. If you want to be able to boot both OSs, I think you need to encrypt the Windows with Windows' method, and Linux with Linux's method.

Comment: that's what I already have, but a pre boot encryption is better (google search says that it's possible but it's very complicated)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "pre-boot encryption". The solution described in the security.stackexchange post uses the multiple forms of encryption as I suggested, though I'm not sure if Truecrypt is still best recommended.